# Magento Fatal error: Call to a member function getSortedChildren() on a non-object

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have installed Magento CE 1.9 version and getting error after calling Catalog on Home page. Issue seems to be related with **list.phtml**.

> ERROR : Fatal error: Call to a member function **getSortedChildren()** on
>   a non-object in
>   mageinc\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml
>   on line 74

I didn't change anything after installation and it seems this issue came with Magento 1.9 edition.

Issue is occurring for both List and Grid view on Catalog page as it is being called for both views.

Is there any best solution to resolve this issue ?

Comment: i think you have not set the block type to list the product.

Comment: Is there any other way to call block instead of **{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="products.home" as="product_home" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" category_id="2"}}** ?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/20984/show-products-on-homepage-magento-1-9

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049034/show-a-category-and-its-products-on-homepage-magento1-9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you just have to delete  the method `->getSortedChildren();` at line 134

```
$_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
```

so you have

```
$_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after');
```

Answer (score 2):

Add these lines in your block section layouts file

```
     <block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.name.after" as="name.after"/>
     <block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.after" as="after"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the code by:

```
<?php
$_nameAfter = $this->getChild('name.after');
// New if here
if($_nameAfter):
    $_nameAfterChildren = $_nameAfter->getSortedChildren();
    foreach($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName):
        $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
        $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
        ?>
        <?php echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml(); ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php
//set product collection on after blocks
$_afterChildren = $this->getChild('after');
if ($_afterChildren):
    $_afterChildren = $this->getChild('after')->getSortedChildren();
    foreach($_afterChildren as $_afterChildName):
        $_afterChild = $this->getChild('after')->getChild($_afterChildName);
        $_afterChild->setProductCollection($_productCollection);
    ?>
    <?php echo $_afterChild->toHtml(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

As seen in: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/20984/show-products-on-homepage-magento-1-9/20996#20996?newreg=c5c83466c28d45259ed36642cfe0a382

Answer (score 0):

Edit this file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
Add this code at 73 and 135 lines

```
                <?php if(!empty($nameAfter = $this->getChild('name.after'))): ?>
```

just before:

```
                    $_nameAfterChildren = $nameAfter->getSortedChildren();
```

and add this code at 82 and 144 line

```
                <?php endif; ?>
```

right after

```
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I do not get the error any more because of your "if" solution, but now I get: no products with this selection. I use this code to get all prods of the category 3 (and there are prods in the cat): <block type="catalog/product_list" name="featured" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
            <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>3</category_id></action>
        </block>

Comment: and on line 184 add this <?php if(!empty($this->getChild('after'))): ?> and on line 192 <?php endif;?> this..

Answer (score 0):

The solution of Pass TeT will throw the PHP Error "PHP Fatal error:  Can't use method return value in write context" because PHP doesn't have concept of emptyness. It's better to use `<?php if($this->getChild('name.after')): ?>` what wouldn't throw an error.

Answer (score -1):

Hey guys I had the same problem - but it was because I hadn't copied all the files from         app/default/default
to
     app/yourTheme/default

I was missing files in the default directory. From my understanding - all files need to be copied.
    /etc
    /layout
    /local
    /template