# Show a CATEGORY and its products on Homepage, Magento1.9

Tags: magento, product

I want to show a Category with its Products on homepage.
Magento has built in option to show New Products on homepage and I have no idea about how to show different categories on homepage. For example I have created a category and I want to show the products in this category on homepage as below:

## Featured Products

Product1 
Product2 
Product3

I have tried below code (from previous posts)

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

But this gives me below error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getSortedChildren() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\magento1901\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml on line 134
```

Apparently code I mentioned above is for previous versions or Magento. However version 1.9.0.1 gives error.

Please guide how to show categories on homepage. Thanks

Comment: Kaiser, i have explain this type of task in the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241181/cms-page-with-layered-navigation-not-working/21242296#21242296

Comment: Hi Amit your previous post is not helping me out. Could you please check my edited question again and advise what should I do.

Comment: hi kaiser, this was fixed

Answer (score 2):

> for new product list in magento 1.9 use this one

```
   {{block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}
```

[image]
**or category wise listing**

The new RWD design has two child blocks for the product list.[more info](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/20984/show-products-on-homepage-magento-1-9)

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.name.after" as="name.after" /> 
<block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.after" as="after" />
```

You can first call your block in CMS Homepage like below:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="4" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Now in your catalog/product/list.phtml find line no 74: and 133

find this code

```
<?php
    $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
    foreach($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName):
        $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
        $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
?>
    <?php echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

replace with

```
<?php
if($this->getChild('name.after')):
    $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
    foreach($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName):
        $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
        $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
?>
    <?php echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml(); ?>
    <?php endforeach; 
endif;
?>
```

go line no 188

add code into

```
if($this->getChild('after')):

//code

endif;
```

Comment: Hi Ravi I have tried above method. It does show products from that category on the homepage but homepage slider and other products have disappeared and I have a below error:   Fatal error: Call to a member function getSortedChildren() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\magento1901\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml on line 183

Comment: Check your condition which can i have added in my ans.

Answer (score 0):

I have a below error: Fatal error: Call to a member function getSortedChildren() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\magento1901\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product‌​\list.phtml on line 183

find this code

```
<?php 
 //set product collection on after blocks
 $_afterChildren = $this->getChild('after')->getSortedChildren();
foreach($_afterChildren as $_afterChildName):
$_afterChild = $this->getChild('after')->getChild($_afterChildName);
$_afterChild->setProductCollection($_productCollection);
?>
<?php echo $_afterChild->toHtml(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

replace code with

```
<?php
if($this->getChild('after')):
//set product collection on after blocks
$_afterChildren = $this->getChild('after')->getSortedChildren();
foreach($_afterChildren as $_afterChildName):
$_afterChild = $this->getChild('after')->getChild($_afterChildName);
$_afterChild->setProductCollection($_productCollection);
?>
<?php echo $_afterChild->toHtml(); ?>
<?php endforeach;
endif;
?>
```