# Can't show products on Magento 1.9 home page

Tags: magento, product, magento-1.9

I'm trying to show a list of all products on the Magento 1.9 home page but all I see is "There are no products matching the selection". I've added the following block into CMS>Home Page>Content:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" 
        alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Tried adding the following with no change:

```
column_count="6" products_count="13"
```

I've also fixed the RWD problem described here:
[Show a CATEGORY and its products on Homepage, Magento1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049034/show-a-category-and-its-products-on-homepage-magento1-9)

I've set the product to be Enabled, set the New range from Nov 2010 to Nov 2020 and I've flushed the cache. The home page still shows:

```
There are no products matching the selection.
```

**Update**

Added the category_id as suggested but no change in the result.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="2" 
        name="home.catalog.product.list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Here's category 2:

[image]

Comment: Did you change the block from catalog/product_list to catalog/product_new?

Comment: No. I'm looking to show all products not new ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a category id in the block. Try adding `category_id="ID"`, for example

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="2" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to filter by category

Comment: then you can pass in your root category id to display all products

Comment: I've added a category_id but am seeing the same results. See update above

Comment: Is the product in stock? It won't get displayed if its qty is 0 or out of stock.

Comment: But Stock Availability was set to Out of Stock - Thanks @subroutines, setting to In Stock fixed the problem. Accepted this as the answer

Answer (score 2):

To display all products on home page, root category should be set as Is Anchor = yes in display setting in manage categories

Comment: I've set this to yes and am still seeing the same results