# Design hampered if list.phtml has been edited to remove fatal error related to getSortedChildren() method

Tags: php, magento

I have installed Magento CE 1.9 version but I am getting error after calling Catalog on Home page. This issue related with list.phtml.

I have searched for relevant solutions to solve this fatal error and got a suitable answer.

I have gone through the below link:

[Magento Fatal error: Call to a member function getSortedChildren() on a non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23654118/magento-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-getsortedchildren-on-a-non-obje)

As per the solution given in the above link I have replaced all codes, but after doing this, error has been disappear, but the design of the home page distorted. Can any one help me in this regards?

Answer (score 0):

I have write following code in home page:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="3" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

I have tried to solve the problem and finally I did it using some **CSS** fixation.

Answer (score 0):

Edit this file app/design/frontend/yourpackagename/yourthemename/template/catalog/product/list.phtml Add this code at 73 and 135 lines
      getChild('name.after'))): ?>

```
just before:


$_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();

and add this code at 82 and 144 line

<?php endif; ?>

right after

<?php endforeach; ?>
```